# How do you sort a list of Object?

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a solution to compare two instances of an Oject so instead of

`list.sort((a, b) => (a.number > b.number) ? 1 : -1)`

I can have simply have `list.sort()`

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) say that in `arr.sort([compareFunction])`, if `compareFunction` is omitted, the array elements are converted to strings, then sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value, so it's not suited for a list of object.

But really, you should stick to precising a compare function, sorting by object key is really not verbose:

```js
const arr = [
  { number: 10 },
  { number: 20 },
  { number: 0 },
  { number: 30 },
]
arr.sort((a,b) => a.number - b.number)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [2,56,12,89,21]
arr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

did you try this one? because we should always return a+b or a-b in sort method otherwise this will not effectable i think

Comment: This is an array of primitive number. What I am looking for is a way to sort an array, Object like so : let arr = [{number:2},{number: 56},{number:12},{number:89},{number:21}]

Comment: ohh ok then wrap this in foreach methodand push values of numbers in any array then try sort